# Implementing circular lists and how to delete a middle node in a list

Tags: c, list, extract, bidirectional, circular-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cir{

    int info;
    struct cir* next;

};

struct cir* create(int num){

    struct cir* temp;

    temp=(struct cir*)malloc(sizeof(struct cir));

    temp->info=num;
    temp->next=NULL;

    return(temp);
}


struct cir* insertlast(struct cir** head0, struct cir* new1){

    struct cir* temp;

    temp=(*head0);

    if(temp==NULL){

        new1->next=new1;

        return(new1);
    }

    else{

        while(temp->next !=(* head0) ){

            temp=temp->next;

        temp->next=new1;
        new1->next=(*head0) ; }

    }

    return(*head0);

}

void vizualize(struct cir* head0){

    struct cir* temp;

    temp=head0;

    printf("Lista:");

    while(head0->next != temp ){

        printf("[%d]-->", head0->info);
        head0 =head0 ->next;

    }

    printf("%d(testa)", head0->info);



}

int main(){

    struct cir* head;
    int i,n1,n2;
    struct cir* new1;


    printf("Insert the number of elements you want to put in  the list:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){

        printf("Insert the element you want to insert in the list:\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &n2);

        new1=create(n2);

        insertlast(&head,new1);
    }

    vizualize(head);

}
```

Hi there! I've written this code to implement a CIRCULAR list, but when I try to run the code it crashes.

I've created the function `struct cir* create(int num)` to create a single element to insert in the circular list list by calling the function `struct cir* insertlast(struct cir** head0, struct cir* new1` to attack the element to the circular list.

Furthermore, as reguard the bidirectional lists:

```
 if(temp->next!=NULL){

        (temp->next)->prev=NULL;
```

what does

```
(temp->next)->prev=NULL;
```

do?

Last question, is there anyone who can write here a code  to delete an element in the middle of a monodirectional list? 
I've tried in any way but everytime I try to delete one element the programm crashes or the list is vizualize in the same way!

Thanks a lot!

ps.which is the difference between deleting and extracting an element from  a list?

Comment: The very first time you enter `insertlast`, `*head0` points nowhere. Learn to use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cir {
    int info;
    struct cir* next;
};

struct cir* create(int num) {

    struct cir* temp;

    temp = (struct cir*)malloc(sizeof(struct cir));

    temp->info = num;
    temp->next = NULL;

    return(temp);
}


struct cir* insertlast(struct cir* head0, struct cir* new1) {

    struct cir* last;

    if ( head0 == NULL ) {

        new1->next = new1;

        return new1;
    }
    else {
        last = head0;
        while (last->next != head0) {
            last = last->next;
        }

        last->next = new1;
        new1->next = head0;

        return head0;
    }
}

void vizualize(struct cir* head0) {

    struct cir* temp;

    if (head0) {
        temp = head0;

        printf("List:");

        do {
            printf("[%d]-->", temp->info);
            temp = temp->next;
        } while ( temp != head0 );
    }
}

int main() {

    struct cir* head;
    int i, n1, n2;
    struct cir* new1;

    head = 0;

    printf("Insert the number of elements you want to put in  the list:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {

        printf("Insert the element you want to insert in the list:\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &n2);

        new1 = create(n2);

        head = insertlast(head, new1);
    }

    vizualize(head);
}
```

Just notice, I've tested it on c++ compiler, not c.

> which is the difference between deleting and extracting an element
>   from a list?

Extract means you remove element from a list and can use it. Delete means you not only remove from a list, but also free memory.

Comment: thanks a lot!last thing: does it mean it works only on c++?

Comment: No, it is a `c` code, just mentioned my compiler for your information

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the insertlast function. The first problem is when there is an insertion and the list is empty (you also forgot to initialize the head to NULL in the main), because you just set the "next" pointer for the new element, without making it the new head of the list.
Then when scrolling through the list, with the way you wrote that while loop, you loop till you find the point of insertion and then exit without actually doing anything.

Here it is a corrected working version of the function:

```
struct cir* insertlast(struct cir** head0, struct cir* new1) {
    struct cir* temp;
    temp = (*head0);
    if(temp == NULL) {
        new1->next = new1;
        *head0 = new1;
        return(*head0);
    }
    else {
        while(temp->next != (*head0)) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new1;
        new1->next = (*head0);

    }
    return(*head0);
}
```

Regarding the meaning of

```
(temp->next)->prev=NULL;
```

in a bidirectional list, it sets the node pointed by "temp" to NULL, since from "temp" you go to the next element, then again to the previous one, which is the same as the beginning (given that "next" and "prev" are correctly set).

Lastly, to delete an element from a  monodirectional list, you have to stop at the element right before you want to delete and rearrange the pointers:

```
while(temp->next->info != target){
      temp=temp->next
}
struct circ* node_to_delete = temp->next;
temp->next = node_to_delete->next;
free(node_to_delete);
```

I don't think there is a well defined difference between extraction and deletion, but usually I consider extraction when I just get an element without removing it from the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! so I have to put parenthesis after every wile? I thought it was optional!

Comment: Parenthesis for every loop/if are optional only if the perform just one instruction. If more lines of code have to be performed, they are mandatory